# Compile errors on datastore import

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm fooling around with Google app engine using GWT, and have run into errors while setting up my interactions with the datastore.

```
[error] The import com.google.appengine.api.datastore cannot be resolved
```

for the line

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
```

and similar. Eclipse has no problem with the imports until compile, suggesting the correct imports and bringing up javadocs. Without the datastore imports the program compiles and uploads without error.

I am using Eclipse 3.7, GWT 2.3, and GAE 1.5.1. The Eclipse configuration looks good, with both Google SDK's listed in the build path tab. The .classpath file contains the line

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER"/>
```

though I don't know where GAE_CONTAINER is set.

I'm sure this is a stupid oversight on my part. But I am also sure I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: Where are you trying to use Datastore? Is it GWT-side or server-side?

Comment: Shifting the Datastore to the server fixed the problem. This restriction seems super-obvious in retrospect, though I still can't find it stated explicitly in the documentation.

Comment: Just note that GWT is compiled into javascript, that will be executed in the browser, so it just cant have any things like datastore and others

Comment: @JaredGarst SO what exactly did you do to fix this? I'm getting the same error, but can't seem to find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Oh lord, this was so long ago. Also I'll bet there are multiple ways to get this exact error.
I was trying to store information serverside from the client side. GWT quite reasonably wanted me to explicitly send it over first. I don't remember the specific API calls that were out of place.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're trying to import `DatastoreService` inside GWT **client code** - the one that gets compiled to javascript.

The error message is produced by the Eclipse GWT Plugin.

Eclipse does suggest this import because `DatastoreService` class is available on the classpath from strictly Java point of view. It's just not available to the GWT compiler.